# Advice for a seminar project in methods for applied sciences

Tags: numerical-methods, advice, biology, computational-science

I am a master student in Mathematics, and I have to prepare a seminar for a course in mathematical methods for applied sciences. I have a good background in numerical analysis for ODEs, PDEs and hence I also would like to run some simulations in Python. I also have some experience with standard numerical methods for SDEs.

The topic of such a talk could be

- chapter from classical Murray's books, so maybe some biological models, but that is of course not mandatory
- I also thought to search for some articles like [this one from SIAM](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/10081856X), but honestly I'm pretty open to other possibilities.

Of course, I do not want the level to be too low, but nor to high, since I'm still a student.

Comment: How long do you have before this must be done?  Should the talk be more biology focused, as in answering a specific question in biology; or should it be more mathematically focused?  If the latter I would suggest taking a look at practical and structural identifiability of models.  This involves both fitting ODE (or PDE though this is more complex) models to data and determining which parameters and combinations of parameters may be identified from data.  If Biology I'd say take a look at *Nature* or *Science* and make a model for something that interests you

Comment: @GeauxMath I have one month. It's about biology or similar, but I should take some model (like SIR, but not SIR) and analyze it, add simulations solving the PDE/ODEs that describe the model, and stuff like that. The important thing is the math behind it, I'd say

Comment: Personally, I'd say stochastic differential equations is a bit to tackle in a month.  I'd pick something that interests you and do a relatively simple model, analyze it, and maybe fit it to data via least squares if time permits.  Keep in mind changing even one functional form in a model can totally change the analysis.  For example you could look at a Lotka-Voltera or SIR, SIRS, SEIR, etc. model where you don't assume mass action (i.e. interaction as simple multiplication) holds.  (1/2)

Comment: I would also probably stick with ODE unless you are both well familiar with a numerical method for solving PDE and have debugged code already.  Speaking from experience, even if you understand what it should do perfectly,this can take a very long time.  If you do solve a PDE; I would for sure stick to one spatial dimension.  Also, if you do this use literally anything but forward Euler. (Bit of a pet peeve of mine: people write super complex and efficient spatial solvers and then use a first order explicit time solver, like what are you doing...) (2/2)

Comment: @GeauxMath I totally agree with your peeve :).  I can say I'm pretty familiar with ODE solvers, MOL, FEM, FVM and so on,  both in MatLab and Python ( to be fair, numerical analysis is what I really like and what I do almost every day, not biology) :)

Comment: If you want to do a physics biology hybrid application you could do one with cell spreading, or s SIR model coupled to an advection-diffusion equation:
     $\begin{equation*}
     \begin{cases}
        \frac{\partial}{\partial t}u_i + \nabla\cdot(vu_i) = \nabla\cdot\left(D\nabla u_i\right) + F_i(t,\mathbf{u}) & \mathbf{x} \in \Omega, t > 0\\
     v_0 = v(\mathbf{x},0),
     \mathbf{u}_0 = \mathbf{h}(\mathbf{x})
    & \mathbf{x}\in\Omega
    \end{cases}
   \end{equation*}$

Comment: @GeauxMath seems interesting. Do you have some reference? :)

Comment: http://hpcf-files.umbc.edu/research/papers/AlenGobbert2007Cholera.pdf -- Cholera

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0006349510002249 -- cell spreading

Comment: Really nice (especially the first one)! I'll have a deeper look, thanks!